# FQL check if each person of my friend-list are friend each other

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

What I want to do is:

Take a friendlist from a fan page and count for each person how many friend he has on that friendlist.

So, for example:

My friendlist is:

```
   -user1
   -user2
   -user3
   -user4
   -user5
```

User1 is friend with user 3 and 4
User2 is friend with user 3
User3 is friend with user 2, 4 and 1
User4 is friend with user 1 and 3
User5 has no friend in common

So I will finally have:

```
User1: 2 friends in the list  
User2: 1 friends in the list 
User3: 3 friends in the list 
User4: 2 friends in the list 
User5: 0 friends in the list
```

I can do it by cycling every user in the friendlist and see the relations. But if you have thousands of friends it could take a while.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I've never used FQL (nor do I like Facebook,) so I'm not going to put an answer in, rather just a comment. Does FQL have an API for mutual friends? This seems to be almost what you're doing. Another thing is, even if you have 1000 friends, if you cycle through the list and read every friend into memory once, and then cycle through memory, it won't take that long. Computers are fast! (Edit: Am just thinking about how long it'll take, it will get exponentially bigger, so I suspect it's O(n^2), but the only way to find out for sure is to test it out)

Comment: Computers are fast.. facebook servers via api are not

Answer (score 0):

You currently cant get a list of people that like your fan page via the api. And also, you won't be able to get a list of friends for those users unless they have authenticated with your api and gave you read_friendlists extended permission.

Comment: But you can verify if a user like a fan page or not! All the user are authenticated in my app so there are no permissions problems.